Nouveau driver Nvidia GeForce 9700M GT
I got an Acer Aspire 8930G with the graphic card Nvidia GeForce 9700M GT. Until now I'm using the nvidia 340.xx driver patch (https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2020/inttf-nvidia-patcher/). Because I get some issues with videoplayback, I want to switch to the nouveau driver. With nouveau I get flickering screen. It's like the screen change it's position in a fast manner. What could be the cause of that?
